# Box shadow causing detrimental effect to image

Tags: css

To start off here is an image to illustrate what I'm dealing with:

[image]

I have seen a few other instances of people dealing with this where a border of sorts is applied to the bottom of an image. A solution was to set the images to display: block, but there was no explanation as to why this fixes it. I'm trying to understand why an image must have a display value of block when applying a box shadow property.

HTML

```
<div id="showcase">
  <section>
    <ul id="gallery">
      <li><img src="img/img1.png" alt="One"></li>
      <li><img src="img/img2.png" alt="Two"></li>
      <li><img src="img/img3.png" alt="Three"></li>
      <li><img src="img/img4.png" alt="Four"></li>
      <li><img src="img/img5.png" alt="Five"></li>
      <li><img src="img/img6.png" alt="Six"></li>
      <li><img src="img/img7.png" alt="Seven"></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 #showcase {
  max-width: 850px;
  border: 2px dotted;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: silver;
 }  

 #gallery {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }

 #gallery li {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  margin: 2.5%;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 10px -5px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're just missing to properly position your **inline-block** images using

```
#gallery img{
    vertical-align: top; /* or any other value from */
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

**Example with issue:**

```css
#gallery li{
  display:inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 10px -5px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="gallery">
  <li>
    <img src="//placehold.it/60x60">
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Example with vertical-align on images**

```css
#gallery li{
  display:inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 10px -5px;
}
#gallery li img{
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<ul id="gallery">
  <li>
    <img src="//placehold.it/60x60">
  </li>
</ul>
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align

[Phrasing HTML elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html) like `img` are subject to *typographical* line-boxes unless set (overridden) to a `block`-level display state.